# How to do drag and drop for a tree control in aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I am currently trying to write a tree control and I have the following custom attributes (draggable and dropplable): Draggable is as follows:

```
@customAttribute('draggable')
@inject(Element)
export class Draggable {
   constructor(element) {
   this.element = element;
}

valueChanged(newValue){
   var el = this.element;
   el.draggable = true;
   el.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
     e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
           // etc.
     if (e.stopPropagation)
       e.stopPropagation();
     return false;
   }, false);
   el.addEventListener('dragend', function (e) {
    this.classList.remove('drag');
    return false;
   }, false);
 }
}
```

etc.
From the droppable attribute I was thinking about a pub/sub mechanism where a view model will pick up the drop and add the data to the tree array.

Is this the best way to do this in aurelia or can I follow some other technique? I guess in angularjs I would do it this way or via the rootscope of the tree.

What are my options?

Comment: It looks good but you need to move the value changed method inside of your class.

Comment: @PWKad : Sorry the formatting is a bit off but the valueChanged method is part of the attribute class. Is that what you mean? Or are you saying the valueChanged method should be in the viewModel class?

Comment: Gotcha, I was looking on mobile and I think you are right it is actually included in the class, just formatted funnily.

Comment: Not sure of a specific answer, but have you looked at this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-dragula

Comment: Did you get this resolved? A lot has changed in 2 years, maybe it's time to close this question?